# Optimizing electoral votes in a political simulation... 200,000+ possibilities, how to run through them?

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, sorting

So basically, in my government class, we are simulating a presidential election. Our grade comes from the presentation of our candidate, but as an added challenge our teacher has a running count of electoral votes garnered. How it works is like this:

1. there are only 18 states amounting to 286 delegates, so 144 needed to win
2. Candidates get a +1 'influence' in certain states (for example home state or somewhere they're popular) and -1, as do VP candidates.
3. Some states (CA and TX) have a pre-existing leaning of up to 2 'influences'.
4. You need to choose 4 issues you're against and 4 you're for, out of a list of 14. Each state has an issue they're against or for. As expected, being in agreement with a state nets you +1 in that state and disagreement nets you -1.
5. If you have more influence in the state, you win it. If it's tied at 0, then the popular vote (the class) gets to decide)

I'm trying to lock up the nomination without even needing to get the popular votes, and I'm trying to figure out what software I could use to do this. I know excel and python 3 at a basic level, but I'm wondering if there's some other way to do it.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNv9p.png) is an image of what I'm talking about (as you can see, I'm playing as the republicans here). Also, the for and against positions formulas link to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPJVZ.png). Now, if I need to choose 4 issues to be for and against, I think that's 14 choose 4 times 10 choose 4, which gives me 210,210 possible combinations. Is there a way to run through all of these to see which will give me the highest Net Electoral Vote count with the lowest closeness factor? Obviously, I don't know my opponents topics yet, but I'd like to have the largest margin of error possible to prevent them from flipping states.

Thanks for any help. tips, advice or comments!

TL;DR: Political simulation, have to find best possible combination of issues to talk about out of 200,000+ possibilities, how do I run through them?

Comment: SO is not meant for open question like yours. Show some code about some trying with a single specific question. Take the [tour]

Comment: SO is not an advice forum, please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python, there are a couple of ways to set up this search.  I like the `itertools` library, which includes functions to conveniently iterate through combinations of things.

Importing and setting up a list of issues:

```
import itertools

issues = [
    "Issue #1", "Issue #2", "Issue #3", "Issue #4", "Issue #5",
    "Issue #6", "Issue #7", "Issue #8", "Issue #9", "Issue #10",
    "Issue #11", "Issue #12", "Issue #13", "Issue #14"
]
```

Now, we can use the `itertools.combinations` function to first choose 8 issues out of the 14 the candidate will be either for or against.

Next, we choose which 4 of the 8 the candidate will be "for".  Then, the remaining 4 issues will be the "against" issues:

```
for candidate_issues in itertools.combinations(issues, 8):
    for for_issues in itertools.combinations(candidate_issues, 4):
        against_issues = list(set(candidate_issues) - set(for_issues))
        # <your code here using for_issues and against_issues>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds complex at first, but the problem should have an easy solution. This should not be based on combinations to start with.

You should be able to calculate easily what is the net result of just choosing a single position across the whole scene. Let's start by selecting nothing and calculating your score based on the biases only. You will get `base-score`.

Then one by one select issues and test what is the outcome of standing on either side. You should get 28 results (2 stands for each of 14 issues) and to calculate this your loop will iterate 28 cases * 18 states = 504 times. You will get a table of scores `issue-stand-scores` and to keep it simple best assume it will be one dimensional, store key-value pairs and keys 0-13 will represent positive stands about the 14 issues, and keys 14-27 negative stands.

Then sort `issue-stand-scores` descending by scored value and choosing first 4 keys in range 0-13 and top 4 keys in range 14-27 will give you the maximum score, which will be the sum of specific values from `issue-stand-scores` at the selected top keys plus the `base-score`. Sorting takes you 28 * log 28 = 28*5 = 140 comparisions.

Now there is a possibility that, after the sort one realizes the situation is flexible, e.g. first 3 keys from 0-13 range give You 3 points each and then there is next 3 keys from that range that give You 2 points each. One can use that situation to and minimize the number of states that are at 0 or otherwise close to swing (-/+1 by the rules of Your game).  Obviously your 4 issues you're positive on will consist in this example of these 3 that give You 3 points each and one of these 3 that give You 2 points each.

To resolve that You first have to mark your limit to choose from, so you would check what is the point count of the 4th key in value order, and continue looking at 5th, 6th, and so on as long as they have the same point value. Once You're there you can make some combinatory loop that checks all the positive variants and all the negative variants and stores the number of "swing states". This is where in the simplest and ineffective implementation, assuming You would be able to choose from half of the positives and half of the negatives, it goes to Combination (4 out of 7) * Combination (4 out of 7) = 35*35 = 1225. Now that would be again looping over all the states, so * 18 = 22050.

So by calculating scores for zero issue situation, and then for each issue individually, then sorting them by score and applying combinatory brute-force approach on wisely limited number of items, You get about 644 "iterations" simply to get the best score, and with the combinatory to find minimum swing scenario, You get about 22694 operations.

Writing the actual solution for base score and for single issues should be simple enough even using excel formulas - just setup two columns for each issue and calculate the issue impact per state, and then total them out. This will give you the scores and You can "sort" manually to choose the best ones. To do the combinatory approach on top of that, i would suggest some real programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you could solve (a generalization of this) efficiently, you could solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem efficiently, which is unlikely.

A typical set cover problem asks if there is a collection of subsets of size k or less which include all members of a larger set. Given such a problem, let the members of the larger set be individual states. Add a number of other states, with biases you can never overcome, so that you can only get a majority by winning the first collection of states. Now set up the issues so that each subset under consideration amounts to an issue, and the members of that subset are the states which will be won if you choose that issue. I think you can organize this so that there is a collection of subsets of size k or less that covers the larger set exactly when there are k issues or fewer that will win you the election if you campaign on them. (If you are worried about "or fewer" just create k dummy issues that nobody cares about).